# How to pass in parameters in spring-mvc-test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I have to test this;

```
/** Displays the balance us page. */
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile/balance")
public ModelAndView balance(Principal principal) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("balance");
    String username = principal.getName();
    User user = userService.findUserByUsername(username);

    model.addObject("moneyEarned", user.getMoneyEarned());
    model.addObject("moneySpent", user.getMoneySpent());

    return model;
}
```

my test looks like that;

```
@Test
public void getProfileBalance() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/profile/balance")
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("balance"));
}
```

I really don't understand how I could pass in that Principal instance. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is by doing

```
@Test
public void getProfileBalance() throws Exception {
    SecurityContext ctx = new SecurityContextImpl();
    ctx.setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("principal", "password"));
    SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_GLOBAL);
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(ctx);
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/profile/balance")
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("balance"));
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
}
```

Or you can use the [Spring Security Test library](https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/07/preview-spring-security-test-method-security)